# Accessing structure members without using dot operator

Tags: c

I don't even know, whether what I'm asking is something stupid or not. I am not asking you to write any code for me, but an idea to do something in a better way.

I have a struct with a large number of items like this:

```
typedef struct _myStruct
{
    int int1;
    char char1;
    int int2;
    :
    :
    int int50;
}myStruct;
```

I have another enumeration which has a single entry for each item in myStruct.

```
enum
{
   eINT1,
   eCHAR1,
   eINT2,
   :
   :
   eINT50
} PARAMETER_ID;
```

I want to write a function for each data type [say one for int, one for char, one for string etc], which return the value of a member of `myStruct`, when the `PARAMETER_ID` is given as input.

For example I need a `int GetInt(PARAMETER_ID)` function which return the value of `int1` when eINT1 is passed as an argument. Similarly I am going to have `char GetCharacter(PARAMETER_ID)`, `float GetFloat(PARAMETER_ID)` etc.

The number of items in the struct can be large. So using a switch-case for each item will not be a viable option.

Only other option I can think of is using the address of the structure variable and `offsetof()` function to calculate the address of the parameter and then by `memcpy`ing the required bytes into a variable. In that case I need to keep the offset of each parameter somewhere, but that is not a problem.

I am looking for alternate options to do this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered arrays ?

Comment: And using a large `switch` is a *good viable* option.... I believe you are wrong in rejecting it...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch:Thanks. I understand. But my boss don't want me to modify these functions every time when a new parameter is introduced :(.

Comment: Won't you need to do that if you take the address route you describe? Where did these bizarre structures come from, and if you need to access them in this way, how did they get designed in such a way?

Comment: @cnicutar:This is all part of an existing code base and I am not allowed to modify the basic implementation since it has some dependencies with other parts of the code.

Comment: @CarlNorum : I am sorry to say that I am forced to work with a code base that is not designed well. Also I am not allowed to change everything since it has some dependencies with other parts of the code.

Comment: Your boss doesn't want you to? Looks like your organization needs to start writing and using tests to catch bugs and regressions.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: I accept that this is a bad design altogether. But IMHO, sometimes people are hesitant to change some code that simply works.

Comment: One day they may discover that it hasn't worked for years. :)

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze : I know. It happened in the past. :) But unfortunately there are limitations to what I could do about this :(

Comment: Are you really sure to really need the `GetInt` function? Why has it not been coded in the first place???

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch The switch only adds needless code overhead and makes the program slower. I see no reason why a switch should be used for this.

Comment: Most dense switch stetments are well optimized as indexed jumps.

Comment: Apparently the struct resides in NVM and is changed between builds. Meaning it has to be volatile, and that all optimizations are off. This changes the question and the answers entirely. For example, the compiler will not be able to optimize a switch statement with a volatile int as input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A large `switch` is a good viable option.

You might also play preprocessor tricks.

You could have a `mystruct.def` file containing

```
 INTFIELD(int1)
 CHARFIELD(char1)
 INTFIELD(int2)
```

etc... Then you would include it several times; to declare the structure:

```
 struct _myStruct {
 #define INTFIELD(F) int F;
 #define CHARFIELD(F) char F;
 #include "mystruct.def"
 #undef INTFIELD
 #undef CHARFIELD
 };
```

To declare the enumeration (using `e_int1` instead of `eINT1`)

```
 enum field_en {
 #define INTFIELD(F) e_##F,
 #define CHARFIELD(F) e_##F,
 #include "mystruct.def"
 #undef INTFIELD
 #undef CHARFIELD
 };
```

To implement the accessor,

```
 int get_int(struct _myStruct*s, enum field_en f)
 {
    switch (f) {
 #define INTFIELD(F) case e_##F: return s->F;
 #define CHARFIELD(F) /*nothing*/
 #include "mystruct.def"
 #undef INTFIELD
 #undef CHARFIELD
    default: return 0;
 }}
```

I don't claim this is better or more readable code, but that kind of programming style does appear in some C or C++ programs (e.g. GCC internals with its `gcc/tree.def`)

If you code is a very large code base, and you are ready to spend days of work (e.g. because you have a lot of such `struct` and don't want to play such tricks) you might consider making a GCC extension with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) (a high-level domain specific language to extend GCC) to help you; you probably can make a MELT extension to generate the accessor functions for you.

You could also convince your boss to generate both the `struct`, the `enum` and the accessor functions from an ad-hoc descriptive file (using `awk`, `python` or whatever). GCC does such tricks for its options file, e.g. `gcc/common.opt`

At last, if the header containing the `_myStruct` is so sacred that you are not allowed to touch it, and if it is very cleanly formatted, you might make an ad-hoc (e.g. `awk`) script to get that declaration and process it.

NB a good compiler optimizes dense `switch` statements as indexed jumps which take constant time, even for hundred of cases.

Comment: You are sir, great. I understand that this is something `not` that easy to do. From the comments I got from all, I think that this design is bad. So I am considering making changes to the design with permission from my boss, so that I can avoid surprises later. :)

Comment: I tend to think that your problem is more a social problem of communication with managers (and usually management sucks, read more about Peter's principle) than a technical problem

Comment: Very true. Sometimes you have to accept something that you know is not good. I hope my manager is not a frequent visitor at SO. :)

Comment: There are two problems with this. First, it isn't random access, it will get logarithmically slower the more items there are in the struct, which may or may not be a concern. Second, it is an unreadable mess. I would solve this with offsetof() and lookup tables instead.

Comment: I don't understand why it is logarithmic. A good compiler optimizes quite well a dense `switch` (usually as an indexed jump, which takes constant time)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yeah I guess, assuming that you have a good compiler. I've seen many compilers do quite obscure optimizations of switches. And no matter, you get a table of jumps instead of a table of values, so unless the compiler can manage to inline away the jump, you get the function calling overhead.

Comment: No, you the switch might be inlined, and you only get the indirect jump, which is constant time (and even if a function is called, it is still constant time). Your solution (array of `offsetof`) is like mine, except that the complexity has moved from code to constant data.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch That may be so, but at least I have ensured that there is no function calling overhead. Anyway, it most often doesn't make sense to write code like this for the sake of optimization. I would go with the most readable code and only consider manual optimization if there is an actual performance problem detected through benchmarking.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct S
{
 int  int1;
 char char1;
 int  int2;
 char char2;
 long long1;
} myStruct = {12345, 'A', 321, 'B', -1L};

enum
{
 eINT1  = offsetof(struct S, int1),
 eCHAR1 = offsetof(struct S, char1),
 eINT2  = offsetof(struct S, int2),
 eCHAR2 = offsetof(struct S, char2),
 eLONG1 = offsetof(struct S, long1),
} PARAMETER_ID;

char GetChar(int para_id)
{
  return *((char*)((char *)&myStruct + para_id));
}

int GetInt(int para_id)
{
  return *((int*)((char *)&myStruct + para_id));
}

long GetLong(int para_id)
{
  return *((long*)((char *)&myStruct + para_id));
}

void main(void)
{
  printf("offsetof int1  = %d\n", eINT1);
  printf("offsetof char1 = %d\n", eCHAR1);
  printf("offsetof int2  = %d\n", eINT2);
  printf("offsetof char2 = %d\n", eCHAR2);
  printf("offsetof long1 = %d\n", eLONG1);


  printf("int1  = %d\n",  GetInt (eINT1));
  printf("char1 = %c\n",  GetChar(eCHAR1));
  printf("int2  = %d\n",  GetInt (eINT2));
  printf("char2 = %c\n",  GetChar(eCHAR2));
  printf("long1 = %ld\n", GetLong(eLONG1));
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Voted +1. :)

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. Consider replacing my functions with this macro: #define Get(type,id) (*((type *)((char *)&myStruct + id)))

Comment: Sure. Looks like some `templating` in C. :)

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have a static tight coupling between the member and its type. That is: in order to get the correct type for member int1 with this code, you must already know that it is of type int. Then you could as well have typed `myStruct.int1`. The whole task only makes sense if you can get a member in a generic manner, like the macro proposed. But then, macros are very bad, there is no type safety, which will be very important here. Use one single function instead.

Comment: @Lundin : I know the type of the data when I call this fns. But as I stated in the questions comment section, this struct changes frequently [which represents the data items in a Flash memory and new parameters will get added frequently] and this calls for adding a new case for each parameter in the function. The code in each case is not trivial. So I was instructed to remove this dependency and that is the only reason I am not opting the switch...case.

Comment: @NeonGlow If it resides in flash memory you ought to use a different approach entirely: you should allocate such data at fixed addresses that remain the same after each build. Consider allocating a lookup table with a pointer at each item, and a corresponding function pointer to a function that handles it. Also, it is dangerous to allocate a struct at fixed addresses in flash unless you can guarantee that there is no padding. Also, if it is in flash it might have to be of type volatile const, which makes the switch solution just as inefficient as I warned about in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

You partially answer your own question, `offsetof` is meant to be used for this very purpose. You have to consider struct padding/alignment. I think you are looking for something similar to this:

```
#include <stddef.h>  // size_t, offsetof
#include <string.h>  // memcpy
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
  int  int1;
  char char1;
  int  int2;
  int  int50;
} myStruct;

typedef enum
{
  eINT1,
  eCHAR1,
  eINT2,
  eINT50,
  ITEMS_IN_STRUCT
} myEnum;


static const size_t MYSTRUCT_MEMBER_OFFSET [ITEMS_IN_STRUCT] =
{
  offsetof(myStruct, int1),
  offsetof(myStruct, char1),
  offsetof(myStruct, int2),
  offsetof(myStruct, int50),
};

static const myStruct MS;
static const size_t MYSTRUCT_MEMBER_SIZE [ITEMS_IN_STRUCT] = 
{
  sizeof(MS.int1),
  sizeof(MS.char1),
  sizeof(MS.int2),
  sizeof(MS.int50)
};



void myStruct_get_member (void* result, const myStruct* ms, myEnum id)
{
  memcpy (result, 
          (char*)ms + MYSTRUCT_MEMBER_OFFSET[id], 
          MYSTRUCT_MEMBER_SIZE[id]);
}
```

Comment: This looks good. Thank you for the complete code. I wish I could accept multiple answers.